# bash - user input - variable

Tags: bash, if-statement, user-input

Say I have something like

```
if [[ "$age" = "12" ]]; then
    "$age" = "twelve"
fi
```

This still returns the number itself. How can I make it become twelve?

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax for assigning a variable is wrong. You can't have whitespace around the "=" and the variable being assigned should not be expanded with "$":

```
age="twelve"
```

The following is a good guide for learning basics and bash syntax: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it.

```
if [[ "$age" = "12" ]]; then
    age="twelve"
fi
```

[Read up on variable assignment in bash.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Going back to 12 from "twelve"?  you should be able to use `if [[ "$age" = "twelve" ]]; then age=12 fi`